# How to enable scrolling in Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, animation, hammer.js

I tried doing the following, but I still couldn't get vertical scrolling to work with the hammer.js element.

```
mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement, {
    touchAction: 'auto',
    recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Pan,{ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL }],
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to support vertical scrolling on `myElement` then you need to add a Vertical Pan recognizer and not the horizontal recognizer.

The code should have been:

```
mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement, {
    touchAction: 'auto',
    recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Pan, { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL }],
    ]
});
```

Comment: From my tests, having touchAction: "auto" is enough.